# android grantPermission() error && java.lang.IllegalStateException:

Tags: exception, permissions, state, sql-grant

Helo!
This is one another self answered question by me. I hope you get a little help.
So.. This is one permission  error about the **sdk23 or higher sdk devices.** **'Cause the permission accepts are changed!**
 **Not the all** permissions are can accepted at the installation moment. This change says that:
***The user have the choice to accept or deny one permission while the app is running.***
Here are the automaticaly granted permissions:

```
android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS
android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE
android.permission.ACCESS_NOTIFICATION_POLICY
android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE
android.permission.ACCESS_WIMAX_STATE
android.permission.BLUETOOTH
android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN
android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY
android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE
android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE
android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE
android.permission.CHANGE_WIMAX_STATE
android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD
android.permission.EXPAND_STATUS_BAR
android.permission.FLASHLIGHT
android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS
android.permission.GET_PACKAGE_SIZE
android.permission.INTERNET
android.permission.KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES
android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS
android.permission.NFC
android.permission.READ_SYNC_SETTINGS
android.permission.READ_SYNC_STATS
android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED
android.permission.REORDER_TASKS
android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES
android.permission.SET_TIME_ZONE
android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER
android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER_HINTS
android.permission.SUBSCRIBED_FEEDS_READ
android.permission.TRANSMIT_IR
android.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT
android.permission.VIBRATE
android.permission.WAKE_LOCK
android.permission.WRITE_SYNC_SETTINGS
com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM
com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT
com.android.launcher.permission.UNINSTALL_SHORTCUT
```

So we don't have any other things to do just **ask the user what he wanna do**.. This is the fund set up. Let's get coding. **The code in the answer section!
 But do not forget to write permissions in the Manifest too for the older android sdk-s!!!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**So here is the code:**
create new int whith dont exist value. Examp: if you have one int with value 1, this int couldn't be 1.. Then this int will be something else.

```
int YOUR_PERMISSION_REQUEST = 1212;
```

&& In the onCreate method

```
//If the sdk level equals or higher than 23.
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23){
        //The permission we wanna accept
        int hasWriteContactsPermission = checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

        //If is not accepted for this app ask the user he wanna accept it or not.
        if (hasWriteContactsPermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            requestPermissions(new String[] {Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                    YOUR_PERMISSION_REQUEST);
        }
```

So you can asks the users to accept one permission. If you wanna ask about other permission you change the READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permissions in the code to your permission. Good Luck. Hope I can help you.

Comment: **If you wanna asks for one more permission do that:**

Comment: Put in the if tag: your**Old**Permission != PackageManager.YOUR_OLD_PERMISSIOn && your**Other**Permission != PackageManager.YOUR_PERMISSIOn

Comment: And put 2 requestPermissions(new String[] {Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                    YOUR_PERMISSION_REQUEST); **with your variables**